# How do I set php check box checked by default?

Tags: php, wordpress

here's the code http://www.evernote.com/l/AoPaANsB0axFa6BCHSofhySrCCnyHTTjg70/. am developing an wordpress plugin, which will hide posts from appearing on homepage, category and archives. if the user checked the option. but now i want to set checked the check boxes by default.

Comment: and what have you tried so far

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1234" checked>

Comment: am trying to create pre-selected check box

Comment: oh thanks @RafaelShkembi you made my life easier.

Comment: just try to read a little bit. :)

Comment: i googling for two days for this one, but you did in one minute. thanks a lot.

Comment: olso if the answer gave you the solution mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a box checked from the beginning you simply have to add  `checked` attributes to your inputs. 
Here is a example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="box" value="1234" checked>
```